# iOS: CoreData fault error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I store all fetched data from CoreData in `NSMutableArray`. When I iterate using `for` loop in this array only I can get first element in the array but the rest of element get me this error: data: 
I know this is expected behaviour, core data won't return full objects until you need to access the persistent values of the objects, but when I try to get an attribute like `NSString *name = [Queue name]`, name is `null` (the problem) and `Queue` is:

```
<Queue: 0x1700b8660> (entity: Queue; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://35A8F411-4740-4A12-8B44-D63667FDD303/Queue/p3> ; data: <fault>)
)
```

Using `[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` the problem persist.

Comment: It has to do with your fetch and your loop. Please show the code.

Comment: There's not enough information to be sure, but your description makes it sound like those values are in fact nil.

Comment: Are you using @synthesize instead of @dynamic in your `Queue` object?